# JUnit5 assertAll private method assertions being ignored

Tags: java, junit5, assertj

Using JUnit5 assertAll, I call a method to perform assertions but noticed that when the assertion should fail, the test actually passes. It seems calling a method like the below is being ignored.

```
assertAll(
    () -> jsonAssertions(actual, expectedUrl)
);

private Executable[] jsonAssertions(String actual, String expectedUrl) {
    return new Executable[] {
        () -> ProductAssert.assertThat(actual).urlEquals(expectedUrl)
    };
}
```

(ProductAssert is a custom assertJ assertion class).

---

This works fine though

```
assertAll(
    () -> ProductAssert.assertThat(actual).urlEquals(expectedUrl)
);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUnit 5 [`assertAll`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertAll-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable...-) takes a list of [`Executable`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/function/Executable.html) instances.

The way you're doing it now, you're not actually passing the `Executable` list to `assertAll`. Instead of passing an anonymous method to `assertAll`, pass the results of `jsonAssertions` directly:

```java
@Test
private void test() {
    assertAll(jsonAssertions(actual, expected));
}

private Executable[] jsonAssertions(String actual, String expected) {
    return new Executable[] {
        () -> assertThat(actual).isNotNull(),
        () -> assertThat(expected).isNotNull(),
        () -> assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected)
    };
}
```

Comment: So what changes do I need to make to the method:

Comment: private Executable[] jsonAssertions(String actual, String expectedUrl) {
    return new Executable[] {
        () -> ProductAssert.assertThat(actual).urlEquals(expectedUrl)
    };
}

Comment: You don't need any changes to your `jsonAssertions` method, just remove the `() ->` from your `assertAll` call.

Comment: @IlyasPatel updated the answer with a more complete example.